# Counting outcomes from a loop?

Tags: python, count

Created a program which flips a coin 100 times and gives a random outcome for each time. Just wondering if it is possible to count the number of times each outcome appears. No idea where to start. What I have so far....

```
# A program which flips a coin 100 times and tells you the outcome each time

import random

counter = 0
flip = ["true", "false"]

while counter <= 99:
    counter = counter+1
    print (counter)
    print (random.choice(flip))
```

Comment: Give two more counters: `counterT` and `counterF` and then store the value of `random.choice(flip)` in a variable  called `RandomV`. If `RandomV==true`{++counterT}else{++counterF}

Answer (score 7):

If 1 represents heads, then the number of heads:

```
import random
print sum(random.choice([0,1]) for x in range(100))
# or more verbose:
print sum('heads' == random.choice(['heads','tails']) for x in range(100))
```

Comment: The brackets aren't needed :), as sum() can be called on a generator expression

Comment: `print sum(random.choice([0,1]) for x in range(100))` -- it's better to omit square brackets since in such case there will be created no intermediate list.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my take

```
heads=0
tails=0
for i in range(100):
  if random.randrange(2) == 0:
      heads+=1
  else:
      tails+=1
```

This is not as clean as a comprehension, but even if you're coming from another language, it's very easy to understand what's going on here.

Answer (score 2):

sum(random.choice((1, 0)) for x in range(100))

Comment: Not really `random.randint(0, 100)` gives a number between 0 and 100. I want 100 1s or 0s.

Comment: You are nearly right `random.randint(1, 100)` would be the answer since both boundaries are inclusive and we need to do it 100 times with 100 being the maximum for either head or tails. Other suggestions. ;)

Comment: Aint that simple. ;) `random.randint(0, 100)` is inclusive both boundaries `random.randrange(0, 100)` is exclusive the upper boundary. Looks like none of them would work if you want 100 tries with 0 as smallest and 100 as biggest value.

Answer (score 2):

You may also want to look at [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
Docstring:
Dict subclass for counting hashable items.  Sometimes called a bag
or multiset.  Elements are stored as dictionary keys and their counts
are stored as dictionary values.
```

---

```
In [1]: import random

In [2]: from collections import Counter

In [3]: Counter(random.choice(('heads','tails')) for _ in range(100))
Out[3]: Counter({'heads': 51, 'tails': 49})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import random
>>> sides = ['heads', 'tails']
>>> headsc = tailsc = 0
>>> for _ in xrange(100):
...     if random.choice(sides) == 'heads':
...         headsc += 1
...     else:
...         tailsc += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
heads = 0
counter = 0
flip = ["true", "false"]

while counter <= 99:
    counter = counter+1
    print (counter)
    result = random.choice(flip))
    if result == "true":
        heads = heads+1
    print (result)
print ("heads: " + heads)
print ("tails: " + (99 - heads))
```

Actually my Python is rusty, so I don't know if my syntax is right, but it should be something close to that.

Comment: You forgot the `else`. Also, you want `==`, not `=`.

Comment: No I didn't. `else` is optional and I don't want to increase a counter or anything if the result of the flip evaluates to `false`. I agree on the `==`, though. As I said I'm rusty. I've just read the docs and fixed it.